# CSS - Layout with columns

Tags: css

I have to make a layout like this: [image: layout-image] (without any plugin if possible).

I thought I can make this layout with CSS columns, but I can't make it work as I want. How can I tell the browser not to cut some column into half?
 Here is my code :

```css
main {
  width: 1253px;    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
}
article {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<main>
<article>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium, esse? Eveniet illum, a hic consequatur ipsa magni maiores eius cupiditate animi odio. Expedita nemo ullam incidunt, facilis optio aliquid, quia!</div>
  <div>Vel, consectetur assumenda possimus sed exercitationem aliquam quo unde, harum et dolor molestiae debitis aperiam, maxime distinctio quam dolorem tempora odit tempore. Ea accusamus velit cupiditate fuga corporis officiis aspernatur.</div>
  <div>Iusto, hic, non suscipit similique eum quos, eveniet dolorum quam atque dolorem sed fugiat, vero deleniti exercitationem recusandae modi libero. Consectetur in non neque facilis, harum. Vel consequatur doloribus id!</div>
</article>
<article>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab et, repudiandae iste commodi eveniet est facilis illum ad voluptas voluptate nisi, ipsam aliquam reiciendis eius alias vero dicta delectus adipisci.</div>
  <div>Atque, cumque, beatae. Quo nihil delectus, officia beatae rem nisi impedit ad iusto ipsum suscipit asperiores aliquam assumenda corporis voluptates repudiandae animi rerum, ab quasi doloremque dolorum modi saepe exercitationem.</div>
  <div>Quo, soluta, ipsum. Soluta, tenetur deleniti accusantium, ratione officia perferendis eius facilis sit blanditiis et dolorum cum illo, dolorem illum magnam repudiandae earum minus esse nobis ullam. Dignissimos, ratione, repellendus.</div>
</article>
<article>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et recusandae totam cumque veritatis laboriosam, ducimus sit ad quibusdam culpa dolorem, qui ut. Quasi suscipit, nostrum! Ratione aspernatur error molestiae, delectus.</div>
  <div>Voluptatum temporibus animi optio eum sequi voluptate excepturi magnam impedit, quo, vero explicabo laborum, placeat! Modi voluptatibus excepturi non? Laboriosam in aspernatur ullam veniam laudantium, corrupti dignissimos optio voluptas earum?</div>
  <div>Recusandae, dolor, sapiente? Quo nemo hic laborum eius. Fugit laborum id magnam, voluptas voluptatum harum ut sapiente sequi aperiam illum impedit molestiae? Non id quo nisi recusandae expedita excepturi, quae!</div>
</article>
<article>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis assumenda, adipisci magnam cupiditate dicta tenetur quia harum sint, esse suscipit quos repudiandae ad, porro amet expedita nemo dolorum quasi provident.</div>
  <div>Aliquid consectetur impedit fugit tenetur harum sequi accusamus minus atque quasi, quas repudiandae, commodi. Beatae, quam! Mollitia alias totam enim vel rem voluptatum, obcaecati sapiente odit sunt necessitatibus aperiam doloremque!</div>
  <div>Suscipit ipsa consequatur eum porro, dolorem. Tenetur molestiae sint nostrum eaque illum ipsum perferendis officiis ab, consectetur enim ratione delectus atque, assumenda impedit. Suscipit id reprehenderit quisquam voluptatum ipsa quasi.</div>
</article>
<article>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In impedit culpa, incidunt illo nesciunt officia, recusandae aut necessitatibus perferendis? Molestias repellendus cumque a adipisci, nesciunt ratione eius libero ut soluta.</div>
  <div>Quas neque aspernatur temporibus beatae consequuntur, reprehenderit cumque necessitatibus facere omnis et perspiciatis. Dolore officia omnis, nostrum corrupti eum ad labore, eius veniam iste voluptate rerum assumenda saepe, dolorum vero.</div>
  <div>Suscipit, molestiae? Atque numquam a eum nostrum nobis sed, commodi, molestias obcaecati velit aliquid quibusdam minima ullam quidem illum earum, perspiciatis officia! Sed ad laboriosam facere alias corporis cumque dolorum.</div>
</article>
<article>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga voluptatum laudantium maxime optio, quidem ad adipisci. Minus sed odio accusamus magnam rem! Dicta recusandae, adipisci autem aliquam asperiores, obcaecati culpa?</div>
  <div>Commodi dolorum aliquid autem ab placeat ex facere magnam itaque obcaecati? Aspernatur eius nobis sit a sed sunt rem ducimus, id aut necessitatibus maxime consectetur officiis voluptas distinctio! Error, omnis!</div>
  <div>Maxime doloremque laboriosam eveniet non pariatur ut sequi, nemo ea distinctio quos accusamus! Eum, ratione doloribus deserunt, corporis facilis, odit officia in quas sed modi, molestias sit. Tenetur, eaque, minima.</div>
</article>
<article>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus facilis unde eveniet culpa praesentium omnis itaque, fugiat nihil iusto blanditiis, veniam perferendis ipsa tempore corporis dolor veritatis quod quisquam saepe.</div>
  <div>Omnis, odio, quia! Perspiciatis iusto illo ducimus, minima voluptas! Officia recusandae doloremque nobis ab ipsam nulla autem eius, rerum expedita? Rem beatae fuga accusamus blanditiis odit praesentium eligendi recusandae est.</div>
  <div>Ullam sequi consectetur perferendis obcaecati, minima fugit nulla quasi provident dolorum quia error veniam necessitatibus voluptatibus ea, exercitationem quo est! Ullam vero, officia iste beatae totam ipsam dolor rerum consectetur.</div>
</article>
<article>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae numquam doloremque eaque fugiat veritatis sit tenetur facilis, officia impedit, rem, unde suscipit libero eius quisquam sunt natus saepe beatae expedita?</div>
  <div>Voluptatum deserunt, esse ipsam dolor provident accusantium accusamus, impedit a obcaecati facilis asperiores. In officia tempora voluptas, ad rem nihil ratione, incidunt maiores et aspernatur mollitia dolorem excepturi quam cum.</div>
  <div>Nobis non voluptatibus doloremque quidem placeat provident expedita dolor id odit quas dolorum labore totam ducimus recusandae voluptatum quis explicabo, autem nihil atque vel aliquam laborum distinctio, quaerat itaque. Impedit.</div>
</article>
<article>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro laudantium ea omnis nihil aut. Culpa eligendi velit harum iusto aperiam, error possimus fuga adipisci officiis laudantium sapiente officia. Rem, quam.</div>
  <div>Placeat impedit sequi tempora assumenda quisquam ad eum repudiandae ab perspiciatis expedita accusamus possimus qui non, id ratione aperiam, quae dolores tenetur culpa debitis est, nostrum quasi autem. Delectus, fugiat!</div>
  <div>Sunt aut laboriosam perspiciatis maiores tenetur, beatae laborum impedit quis debitis porro animi explicabo esse magni cum nihil unde quod veritatis, quibusdam saepe sapiente placeat illo mollitia assumenda? Expedita, ea.</div>
</article>

</main>
```

As you can see some of the columns are cut in half. :(

Somebody can help me? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to `article`

https://jsfiddle.net/7f9so74a/1/

Comment: Your example doesn't work, it appears in 3 column while column-count is 4. :O

Comment: that's just by chance, due to the number and length of articles, when the browser tries to distribute the content evenly across the columns. If you add more articles, you see content in all 4 columns: https://jsfiddle.net/tw410hob/1/

Comment: What I mean is: When you have 9 articles in 4 columns, it will put 3 into the first column (beacuase starting with 2, the 9 wouldn't fit into 4 columns). So the second and third column also get 3 articles, which leaves the fourth column empty in this particular case (but it's there!). If you add or delete articles, they'll be distributed over all four columns.

Answer (score 0):

To keep specific elements together add `break-inside: avoid`

https://jsfiddle.net/s0meg2rt/2/

Comment: It is better, but do you know how to remove the gap before the second column?